# Unable to determine why canvas drawImage is not able to process PNG images

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, drawimage

canvas drawImage() is not working on any other image except one PNG image. Every other image is throwing an error.

```
class Enemy {
constructor(x,y,speed) {
// Variables applied to each of our instances go here,
// we've provided one for you to get started

// The image/sprite for our enemies, this uses
// a helper we've provided to easily load images
this.sprite = 'images/enemy-bug.png';
this.x = x;
this.y = y; 
this.speed = speed;
}

// Update the enemy's position, required method for game
// Parameter: dt, a time delta between ticks
update(dt){
// You should multiply any movement by the dt parameter
// which will ensure the game runs at the same speed for
// all computers.

this.x += this.speed * dt;
if(this.x > 505){
    this.x = -50;
}
// console.log(`In enemy update loop`);

}

// Draw the enemy on the screen, required method for game
render() {
ctx.drawImage(Resources.get(this.sprite), this.x, this.y);
}};

// Now write your own player class
// This class requires an update(), render() and
// a handleInput() method.

class Player{
constructor(x,y){
this.player = 'images/Heart.png';
this.x = 209;
this.y = 405;
}

update(){
// console.log(`player x is ${this.x} and player y is ${this.y}`);
if(this.y === -10){ console.log('Congrats!!');}
}

render(){
ctx.drawImage(Resources.get(this.player), this.x, this.y);

}

handleInput(evtObj){
switch (evtObj) {
    case 'left': 
        if(this.x != 7) {this.x -= 101;}
        break;
    case 'right':
        if(this.x != 411) {this.x += 101;}
        break;
    case 'down' :
        if(this.y != 405) {this.y += 83;}
        break;
    case 'up' :
        if(this.y != -10) {this.y -= 83;}
        break;
}
    // console.log(`x is ${this.x} and y is ${this.y}`);

}};

let checkCollisions = () => {
// console.log('In checkCollisions');
// console.log(`this.y is ${enemy2.y} and player.y is ${player.y}`);
allEnemies.forEach(enemy => {
    // console.log(`enemy.y is ${enemy.y} and player.y is 
${player.y}`);
    if(player.y <= enemy.y + 42 &&
        player.y >= enemy.y - 42 &&
        player.x <= enemy.x + 50 &&
        player.x >= enemy.x - 50){
    player.x = 209;
    player.y = 405;    
    console.log(`Collision!!`);
 }})}

// Now instantiate your objects.
// Place all enemy objects in an array called allEnemies
// Place the player object in a variable called player

const enemy1 = new Enemy(101, 60, 101);
const enemy2 = new Enemy(202, 150, 150);
const enemy3 = new Enemy(303, 225, 190);
const player = new Player();
const allEnemies = [enemy1, enemy2, enemy3];


// This listens for key presses and sends the keys to your
// Player.handleInput() method. You don't need to modify this.
document.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
const allowedKeys = {
    37: 'left',
    38: 'up',
    39: 'right',
    40: 'down'
};

player.handleInput(allowedKeys[e.keyCode]);
});

// animating heading
let pos = -60;
const getHeading = document.getElementById('heading');
const moveHeading = () => {
if(pos === 0){
    console.log(`pos is 0`);
    clearInterval(move);}
else {    
// console.log(`pos is ${pos}`);    
pos ++;
getHeading.style.top = `${pos}px`;
}
}
let move = setInterval(moveHeading, 10);


// adding menu of characters to choose from 

const charList = document.querySelectorAll('.char');
// console.log(charList);
const charUrls = ['images/char-boy.png', 'images/char-cat-girl.png', 
'images/char-horn-girl.png', 'images/char-pink-girl.png', 
'images/char-princess-girl.png'];

let i=0;
const charSelect = (evtObj) => {
const target = evtObj.target.parentElement.id;
switch (target) {
    case 'one': 
        player.player = `${charUrls[0]}`;
        break;
    case 'two':
        player.player = `${charUrls[1]}`;
        break;
    case 'three' :
        player.player = `${charUrls[2]}`;
        break;
    case 'four' :
        player.player = `${charUrls[3]}`;
        break;
}
// player.player = target;
}
charList.forEach((cval) =>{
cval.innerHTML = `<img src= ${charUrls[i]} alt="cat girl 
character">`;
cval.addEventListener('click', function(evtObj){
    charSelect(evtObj);
})
i++;
});
```

When I click on the element the event listener is attached to, I expect the url at player.player to replaced by the corresponding url from the charUrls array. However, I keep getting an error:

```
app.js:52 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 
'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type 
'(CSSImageValue or HTMLImageElement or SVGImageElement or 
HTMLVideoElement or HTMLCanvasElement or ImageBitmap or 
OffscreenCanvas)'
at Player.render (app.js:52)
at renderEntities (engine.js:158)
at render (engine.js:143)
at main (engine.js:49)
at init (engine.js:69)
at resources.js:59
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at Image.img.onload (resources.js:59)
```

The only image working is the 'images/char-boy.png', every other one throws this error and I'm not able to figure out why.

Here is the git repo for a macro view of the project: https://github.com/speedrage56/arcadegame2/tree/otherfeatures

Comment: Figured it out, the images weren't loading. I added them to the Resources.load in the engine.js file and it now works properly.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, the images weren't loading. I added them to the Resources.load in the engine.js file and it now works properly